# how to get the previous value of a cell in a function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am currently trying to set up a simple calculation in google sheets that will only add when the value is not equal to the previous value. How can I go about this? All I need is to get the previous value in from the input. It has been a while since I have given my hand at JavaScript so I could be forgetting something simple like that.

I have tried looking into the google API and looking to similar solutions for help. I could just be dumb or missing something simple but does anyone have any idea?

```
///Call onEdit that takes in the value of e
function onEdit(e) 
{
  //Get the input value and its previous value
  var input = e;
  var previous = e; //.prev();? .offset??

  //Check if cell is updated
  if ( input != previous )
  { return true; }
  else
  { return false; }
}
```

Comment: do you have old value outside of this function?

Answer (score 1):

That way

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(e.oldValue);
}
```

[More details on the event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: When putting that in I am getting the following:
"TypeError: Cannot read property "oldValue" from undefined. (line 6, file "onEdit")"
Any help there as to what could be causing this?


My code updated:
```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  //Get the input value and its previous value
 //Get the input value and its previous value
  var input = e;
  var previous = input.oldValue;
  //Check if cell is updated
  if ( input != previous )
  { return true; }
  else
  { return false; }
}
```
I am new here sorry for the struggles I am having

Comment: The old value is is undefined when you initially provide the content for the empty cell. Then on the second edit you will get both the `oldValue` and the `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You function could be summarised as:

```
function onEdit(e){
  return e.oldValue != e.value;
}
```

However, I believe that if you just put the same value back in the cell, it's not going to be considered an edit, and thus won't trigger the `onEdit()` function. So this will always return `true` when it runs, and not run at all in all other cases.